# In python, how to refer to NoneType?

Tags: python

Let's say I have on object x.
I want to check if x is of a type I support (let's say it's lists, sets, strings and None. And without types that inherit from them), so I figured I'll just check

```
type(x) in (list, set, str, NoneType)
```

However, NoneType cannot be referable.
Is there a clean solution, or must I do something like this?

```
x is None or type(x) in (list, set, str)
```

Is there a standard way to access `<type 'NoneType'>`?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean `type(None)` ?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of that. Though I still think developers should have access to NoneType.

Comment: IIRC, they were going to put `NoneType` to `types` along with other inaccessible types (`FunctionType`, `FrameType`, etc.) in 3.0, until Guido asked (a) whether anyone could imagine writing `types.NoneType` instead of `type(None)` (after all, digging up a frame object to call `type` on it isn't trivial, but `None` is always right there), and (b) whether there was a good use for `isinstance` checks on `None` except as part of some set you built up out of like (since there is only one `NoneType` value, and you're supposed to test it with `is`), and everyone agreed he was right.

Comment: I prefer this: `isinstance(x, (str, list, set, type(None)))`. I'm also interested in figure out which approach could be considered more pythonic.

Comment: @slackmart this won't work If I want to exclude types that inherit from str \ list\ set

Comment: Could you please update the question mentioning this last requirement?

Comment: @slackmart done

Comment: Good anecdote @abarnert Could you please share a link to the actual source of that? :)

Comment: @slackmart Searching the py3k list archives takes time. If a good question comes up where it's relevant to a good answer, someone (maybe me) should do that, but I don't think it's worth the effort here.

Comment: @abarnert actually in my Python 2.7.10 I can access types.NoneType so thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 5):

How about `type(None)`? Just do:

```
type(x) in (list, set, str, type(None))
```

seems to work for me, and is quite clear to me at least. Since there is only one value of `NoneType`, using it as a literal is hardly "magic".

Comment: Wow, didn't think of that! I guess it's probably better than my idea of "type(x) is None or type(x) in (list, set, str)"

Comment: @user2594596 You mean `x is None` not `type(x) is None`. Anyway that's not necessarliy a bad solution. A bit less readable. But it would be even better if you didn't allow `x` to have different types at all.

Comment: @freakish thanks, fixed my typo. I need to filter a list from unsupported types so there's no escape.

Comment: @user2594596 Right, by why would you allow different types in the list in the first place? I.e. instead of doing `type(x) in (a,b,c)` why not simply `isinstance(x, MyClass)` and only allow `MyClass` in the list (and get rid of `None` as well). IMO mixing unrelated types in a list is not a good practice.

Comment: @freakish isinstance will include inherited types which I need to avoid

Comment: @user2594596 That's a weird thing to avoid to be honest. Usually in OOP you want to have objects with a common base class/interface in a list. Usually **you want** `isinstance` instead of directly checking types. Perhaps you have a case were it is ok. But I strongly suggest you rethink the architecture.

Comment: @freakish The problem is that Python allows multi-inheritance. I can deal with lists, I can deal with sets, but If I'll get a class which inherits from both I may process it wrongly. In that case I prefer to ignore the object completely (I know it is not possible to inherit from list and set, and used it only as an example. I am actually dealing with non-builtin types).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access it without calling `type()` you can always refer to its `__class__`, i.e.

```
type(x) in (list, set, str, None.__class__)
```

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `type(None)`, from 3.10+, the *types* module in the standard library ships with [`NoneType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.NoneType), so, e.g., to check if a value is either a float or None, you can do

```
>>> from types import NoneType
>>> value = 12.4
>>> isinstance(value, (float, NoneType))
True
>>> value = None
>>> isinstance(value, (float, NoneType))
True
```

A backwards compatible way for this would be adding `NoneType = type(None)` at the top of the file.